# How to get 5v 2a from low voltage, high amperage solar panels

Tags: voltage, current, dc, solar-cell, 5v

I am attempting to make a usb solar charger from 8 solar panels.
Each solar cell rated as such:

- Max Voltage: 0.574 V
- Max Current: 2.915 A

From what I understand if I connect 8 of these panels in series, their voltages add up to a total of 4.592 V @ 2.915 A

Firstly, how can I set up a circuit so I get a steady flow of 5V and a maximum of 2A from the solar panels, while still allowing for headroom, meaning that if ideal weather conditions aren't met, causing the panels' voltage and amperage to drop, I would still get 5V but amperage could be allowed to drop?

I've browsed the web for up-step voltage regulators but they mainly deal with maximums of 500mA. What other solutions are there, or can I hook up multiple voltage regulators to get a max of 2A? Additionally 8 solar panels is the maximum amount of panels I can fit on my project.

Answer (score 1):

A DC/DC boost converter seems like a good solution to me. The closer to 5V your input is, the more efficient it will be and the more current you will be able to get out of it.

You see a lot of 500mA because that's the USB standard.

There are beefier converter out there, going all the way down to an input voltage of 1V. You could also design your own using TI's tool: webbench (I like using it as a starting point in my designs). But it probably makes sense to buy one off the shelf.

Searching for "dc dc boost 1V to 5V 2A" gave me one hit on bangood for 0.99USD ... There are other, more expensive and more reputable around.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is they you're less likely to find integrated one-chip boost-converters for higher current outputs ... what you start looking for are converter controller chips that expect you to have external power transistors to handle the loads